# Environment with a switch

Tags: macros, environments

I am trying to build an environment with a switch, so that -- when turned on - only the text in the Brackets appear in the pdf file.

It would be great, if exceptions are possible and for marked* items the whole text could be printed.

Does something like this exist? I could not find an example.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[ABC] 12345
\item[CDEF] 098765
\item*[xxxx] yyyyy
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `environ` for manipulating the environment's contents more easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{xdesc}
 {
  \begin{description}
  \cp_xdesc_main:NV \xdescitemshow \BODY
  \end{description}
 }

\NewEnviron{xdesc*}
 {
  \begin{description}
  \cp_xdesc_main:NV \xdescitemhide \BODY
  \end{description}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cp_xdesc_main:Nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_cp_xdesc_items_in_seq { \item } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_cp_xdesc_items_in_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l_cp_xdesc_items_out_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_cp_xdesc_items_in_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_cp_xdesc_items_out_seq { #1 ##1 \endxdescitem }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_cp_xdesc_items_out_seq { }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cp_xdesc_main:Nn { NV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\xdescitemshow}{sO{}+u{\endxdescitem}}
 {
  \item[#2] #3
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xdescitemhide}{sO{}+u{\endxdescitem}}
 {
  \item[#2] \IfBooleanT{#1}{#3}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Show}

\begin{xdesc}
\item[ABC] 12345

\item[CDEF] 098765

\item*[xxxx] yyyyy
\end{xdesc}

\section{Hide}

\begin{xdesc*}
\item[ABC] 12345
\item[CDEF] 098765
\item*[xxxx] yyyyy
\end{xdesc*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to collect the contents and splitting it at `\item`; the first item will be empty and we throw it away. Then we process each item by adding in front of it either `\xdescitemshow` or `\xdescitemhide` and ending them with the sentinel `\endxdescitem`; the two commands process their arguments inserting `\item`, collecting the optional argument (and possibly the `*`), then printing or discarding the following text up to `\endxdescitem`.

### Update March 2019

With new features of `expl3` (`\seq_map_variable:NNn`) and `xparse` (the implementation of features alike to `environ`), the code can be simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xdesc}{+b}
 {
  \begin{description}
  \cp_xdesc_main:Nn \xdescitemshow { #1 }
  \end{description}
 }{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{xdesc*}{+b}
 {
  \begin{description}
  \cp_xdesc_main:Nn \xdescitemhide { #1 }
  \end{description}
 }{}

\seq_new:N \l_cp_xdesc_items_seq
\tl_new:N \l__cp_xdesc_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cp_xdesc_main:Nn
 {
  % split the input at \item
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_cp_xdesc_items_seq { \item } { #2 }
  % throw away the first element, that's empty
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_cp_xdesc_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  %
  \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_cp_xdesc_items_seq \l__cp_xdesc_temp_tl
   {
    \exp_last_unbraced:NV #1 \l__cp_xdesc_temp_tl \stopxdescitem
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\xdescitemshow}{sO{}+u{\stopxdescitem}}
 {
  \item[#2] #3
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xdescitemhide}{sO{}+u{\stopxdescitem}}
 {
  \item[#2] \IfBooleanT{#1}{#3}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\stopxdescitem}{}{} % for safety

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Show}

\begin{xdesc}
\item[ABC] 12345

\item[CDEF] 098765

\item*[xxxx] yyyyy
\end{xdesc}

\section{Hide}

\begin{xdesc*}
\item[ABC] 12345
\item[CDEF] 098765
\item*[xxxx] yyyyy
\end{xdesc*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's clever: so you split `\BODY` using `\item` and then process the pieces. I'm still wrapping my head around around expl3: why do you use `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cp_xdesc_main:Nn { NV }` rather than `\cs_new_protected:NV \cp_xdesc_main:Nn{...}`? Does the latter not exist?

Comment: @Andrew The latter would not mean the same thing. `\cp_xdesc_main:NV` absorbs as its second argument the contents of a variable and passing it to `\cp_xdesc_main:Nn` as if it were explicit.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a package that does this. If you are prepared to enclose the "item text" in braces so that for each item you type something like:

```
\Item[ABC]{12345}
```

then this is relatively straightforward to do using the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package. All that you need to do is define an `\Item` command that takes three arguments:

- an optional `*`
- an optional label for the `\item` command, and,
- the "item text"

The `\Item` command then processes the input using the tools described in the  (see the xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) manual and then does the appropriate things.

For example, you get the output

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newif\ifMySwitch% a "switch" for turning othe item text on/off

\NewDocumentCommand\Item{ som }{% *[label]{text}
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{ \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\item #3}{\item[#2]#3} }
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\item}{\item[#2]}\ifMySwitch #3\fi}
}

\begin{document}

  Switched on: \MySwitchtrue
  \begin{description}
    \Item[ABC]{12345}
    \Item[CDEF]{098765}
    \Item*[xxxx]{yyyyy}
  \end{description}

  Switched off \MySwitchfalse
  \begin{description}
    \Item[ABC]{12345}
    \Item[CDEF]{098765}
    \Item*[xxxx]{yyyyy}
  \end{description}

\end{document}
```

If you are not happy enclosing the "item text" in braces this is slightly trickier. The easiest way out that I see is to assume that the "item text" contains at most one paragraph, which seems reasonable to me, and then *require* that every item ends with a blank line. In particular, the very last item needs a blank line before the `\end{Description}`.

If you assume this then you can essentially repeat the code above but now the item command delegates everything to a `\greedyItem` command that reads in everything up to the end of the next paragraph as the item text. For LaTeX the "end of the next paragraph" means the next `\par`, which is why `\par` appears after the `#3` in the definition of `\greedyItem`. The following code achieves this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{Description}{description}{3}% a new description environment
\setlist[Description]{before=\let\item\Item}% in which the switch is automatic
\let\realItem=\item% save the "real" item for future use
\usepackage{xparse}
\newif\ifMySwitch% switch on/switch off

\def\greedyItem[#1][#2]#3\par{% #3 = until end of paragraph
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{ \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\realItem #3}{\realItem[#2]#3} }%
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\realItem}{\realItem[#2]}\ifMySwitch #3\fi}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\Item{ so }{\greedyItem[#1][#2]}

\begin{document}

  Switched on: \MySwitchtrue
  \begin{Description}
    \item[ABC]12345

    \item[CDEF]098765

    \item*[xxxx]yyyyy

  \end{Description}

  Switched off \MySwitchfalse
  \begin{Description}
    \item[ABC]12345

    \item[CDEF]098765

    \item*[xxxx]yyyyy

  \end{Description}

\end{document}
```

Btw, I have switched to using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package, which I prefer, and added a few bells and whistles to hide the code inside a new `Description` environment, which is the just the usual `description` environment with your switch automatically incorporated. The output is the same as before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test both solutions. Very great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @C.-P. You thank on TeX.SX by up-voting and awarding a green tick to the best answer, if any, that answers your question. You should go back over your previous posts and do this.